# cURL Error 51 when Posting to Force.com

Tags: rest-api, force.com, ssl, curl

I have a form on my WordPress website that collects additional information from Leads.  I want this information added to an existing Lead record, so I made a WordPress plugin that initializes a cURL `PATCH` request like so:

I'm able to do this because I'm exposing a public API via an Apex class.  Yeah, I know it's not as secure as OAuth, but I want non-logged in users to be able to submit the form. I would use Salesforce's Username-Password OAuth flow for this, but it has come to my attention that it is not secure and should only be used for development with Sandboxes ([source](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/116507/47219)).  Additionally, the API that I am exposing is quite limited (you can't create new records or delete existing ones; you can only edit a few custom fields of a record).

Here is a demonstration of the kind of API that I am exposing:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myendpointgoeshere/*')
global class FooBar {

    @HttpPatch
    global static void doPatch(String someEmailAddress, String theNewFieldVal) {

        // indented so you can clearly see what's going on
        List<MyCustomObject__c> results = [
            SELECT Some_Field__c 
            FROM MyCustomObject__c 
            WHERE Email__c = :someEmailAddress
        ];

        for(MyCustomObject__c o : results){
            o.Some_Field__c = theNewFieldVal;
        }

        update results;
    }

}
```

Here is the PHP class method that initializes the cURL request; it is called after the form is submitted.

Basically, it is posting three field values to my Force.com site.

```
public function patch_salesforce($field1, $field2, $field3) {
    $url = 'https://<MY_INSTANCE>.force.com/<MY_SITE>/services/apexrest/...';

    $content = json_encode(array(
      'field1' => $field1, 
      'field2' => $field2,
      'field3' => $field3
    ));

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($status != 200) {
        die("Error: call failed with status $status, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

This code works without any errors.  I know this because I tested it with my Sandbox, but now I want to take it live, so I swapped out the Sandbox Force.com URL with the Production org's URL.

After doing so, I'm met with this error:

```
Error: call to URL failed with status 0, curl_error SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '<MY_INSTANCE>.force.com', curl_errno 51
```

I spent some time researching cURL error code 51.  I was presented with the following solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842970/fix-curl-51-ssl-error-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches) StackOverflow post.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

I'm hesitant to use that solution because it is insecure and can leave me vulnerable to a Man-in-the-Middle attack.  Many people don't recommend using it.  Also, it seems like a "lazy" fix.

My questions:

- Is there any other way to fix this?
- Is the problem with my web host, website, or Salesforce?
- Should I be concerned with Man-in-the-Middle attacks?
- Should I use the "lazy" solution above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any other way to fix this?

In theory, yes. You can go to Setup > Security Controls > Certificate and Key Management, upload some new certificates, and assign them to your Site via custom URLs. You'll probably need your own domain or subdomain name to make this work correctly. I don't have a production org I can experiment with, so you'll want to engage Developer Support if possible.

> Is the problem with my web host, website, or Salesforce?

It's your Salesforce configuration. You can fix this if you're willing to go through the effort required to do so. Some money might be involved if you need to set up a custom domain name.

> Should I be concerned with Man-in-the-Middle attacks?

Most hosted networks are secure enough that the threat is virtually non-existent. That said, there is a tangible possibility that someone could figure it out and exploit it, however slim of a chance that might be. I would argue that anyone who's gotten far enough to figure out how to exploit this probably already has access to your WP server or its network, which means that such an exploit should be the least of your worries.

> Should I use the "lazy" solution above?

Given the limited amount of damage that could be done with this endpoint, I don't think I see much harm in being lazy in this specific circumstance. I would recommend that you at least enable Field History Tracking for those fields that will be modified so you have a point of reference if something goes sideways (you could always export and re-import records that are modified, for example).

As always, make sure your Apex Code can't be exploited either. Verify your inputs, make sure that only the specified fields can be modified, etc. With field tracking and some modest security practices in your code, I don't see any unusual risk from anyone that doesn't already have at least as much risk (e.g. your employees that have access to Salesforce).

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox, thanks for your help on this question and on my other ones; I appreciate it because I'm not a Salesforce developer!  I edited my post to include a demo of the API I'm exposing (it's not exact of course).  In your opinion, do you think that API is limited and safe?

Comment: I mean, to do any damage: a bad guy would need to know my instance, Force.com site name, and API endpoint.  Then, they'll need to get a valid email address attached to an existing record. And then they'll need to pass in the correct argument names.  Additionally, my WP plugin has a few security measures implemented.  For example, the plugin cannot be called or accessed directly and the root file (index.php) is a blank page.  I'll use the "lazy" method as a last resort.  I'll read up on Salesforce Certificate and Key Management first.  Again, thank you so much for your help!