# Update a Record's Fields in Production Org from External Website w/o Salesforce Login

Tags: api, force.com, oauth, certificates, curl

I have a form on my WordPress website that collects additional information from customers. I want this information added to an existing record of `MyCustomObject`.  To do this, I will need to make a custom WordPress plugin that sends the data to Salesforce via the cURL PHP library.

How should I go about doing this **without having a user logging into Salesforce**? I would use Salesforce's Username-Password OAuth flow for this; however, as stated in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116406/when-to-use-username-password-flow-to-obtain-a-token/116507#116507) forum post, it is not secure and should only be used for development with Sandboxes.  **Is that true?**

At this point, I feel as though I have no other choice but to use the Username-Password OAuth flow; I'm not a Salesforce developer so I have no idea about a good and secure way of going about this.  Moreover, what I have right now only works if I send the data to a developer Sandbox.  When I try to change it to send it to my Production org, I get errors like `cURL 51, HTTP 500, HTTP 501`. **My thought process is that if I stop using what I have now (the Force.com APEX REST API) and use Username-Password OAuth (or something else), such errors would be resolved.**

As stated previously, I currently have a public APEX REST API on a Force.com site ([I followed this tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html)).  Below is a simplified demonstration of what I've come up with.  You'll notice that it is very limited  (you can't create new records or delete existing ones; you can only edit a custom field of a record).

Essentially, what the API allows me to do is pass in two parameters: `someEmailAddress` and `theNewFieldVal`.  `someEmailAddress` is used to query the records and find all of them that have the supplied email (in other words, it finds records where `Email__c` is `someEmailAddress`).  I then loop through all of the records and set `Some_Field__c` to `theNewFieldVal`.

So, to recap, `someEmailAddress` is merely a way to find the record(s) I would like to update, and `theNewFieldVal` is the new value of `Some_Field__c`.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/myendpoint/*')
global class FooBar {

    @HttpPatch
    global static void doPatch(String someEmailAddress, String theNewFieldVal) {

        // indented so you can clearly see what's going on
        List<MyCustomObject__c> results = [
            SELECT Some_Field__c 
            FROM MyCustomObject__c 
            WHERE Email__c = :someEmailAddress
        ];

        for(MyCustomObject__c o : results){
            o.Some_Field__c = theNewFieldVal;
        }

        update results;
    }

}
```

I use the above API with the following `PATCH` cURL request in my WordPress plugin:

```
public function patch_salesforce($someEmailAddress, $theNewFieldVal) {
    $url = 'https://<MY_COMPANY>.force.com/<MY_PATH>/services/apexrest/myendpoint';

    $content = json_encode(array(
        'someEmailAddress' => $someEmailAddress,
        'theNewFieldVal' => $theNewFieldVal
    ));

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($status != 200) {
        die("Error: call failed with status $status, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
}
```

That all works well in development with a Sandbox, but when I changed `$url` from my Sandbox's Force.com URL to my Production org's Force.com URL, I was greeted with the following error:

```
Error: call to URL failed with status 0, curl_error SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '<MY_INSTANCE>.force.com', curl_errno 51
```

I then spent some time researching cURL error 51, and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842970/fix-curl-51-ssl-error-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches) post.  It suggests to add the following to my cURL settings:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

I tried that and got this error:

```
Error: call to URL failed with status 501, curl_error , curl_errno 0
```

If I try using only `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, I get the same error.

If I try using only `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, I get the original cURL 51 error.

Also, **do I need the `.secure` in `$url`?  Because I tried that and kept getting `500` errors**.

@sfdcfox pointed out that one possible solution is to add a new certificate in Salesforce's Certificate and Key Management setup section, **but which API client certificate should I use? Self-signed or one issued by a CA?**

Comment: If you are exposing the rest class to a public site you do not need to authenticate at all. Simply post the data to the site URL and let your apexclass handle it

Comment: @Eric I know, but I'm getting an error when I swap out my developer Sandbox URL with my Production org URL.  I get cURL error code 51.  Do I need to have a certificate in my production org?

Comment: Check your urls. Add a get to you rest class and hit it with your browser to test. At least then u will know if the URL you are trying to access is correct or not. Postman is also a good tool for troubleshooting

Comment: @Eric, that's a good idea.  I'll try it -- thanks!

Comment: @Eric, I really don't think the URLs are the problem, though.  [Here are the URLs I'm using.](https://i.imgur.com/NOIgtwm.png).  (the site label/name and path are the same).  I tried it with & without the `.secure`, too.  Question: should Username-Password OAuth flow be only used for development with Sandboxes, or can they be used in Production?

Comment: If the site is public there is NO auth flow. You simply hit the URL. Authentication is not needed. Only use the auth flow if you are using the api's

Comment: @Eric, no I would use a Connected App instead.  Sorry, I should of stated that haha.  Thanks for the help, btw.

Comment: Your comments do not match your question then. The linked article and your examples have nothing todo with a connected app. Pick one or the other

Comment: @Eric - I apologize; this question is sort of unrelated.  Would it be a good practice to use the Username-Password OAuth flow (with a Connected App) in Production?

Comment: The best way would be the oAuth token flow.

Comment: @Eric Ohh, okay; I wanted to use it as an alternative to the public Force.com Rest API that I have.  My issue is that I want to send data from my WordPress site to Salesforce.  The customers won't be able to login to Salesforce to authorize the connection.

Comment: @Eric Hey, what course of action do you suggest if I wanted to get data into my Salesforce Production org from an external website without having my visitors authorizing with Salesforce?  Someone else suggested using an Inbound Email Handler to send emails to Salesforce.  You've been very helpful so far; I appreciate it.